# .NET reflection - Get Declaring class type from instance property

Tags: .net, reflection, gettype

Is it possible to get the type of a class from a property instance

I tried the following

```
var model = new MyModel("SomeValueForMyProperty")

Type declaringType = model.MyProperty.GetType().DeclaringType
```

But the result is always not for both DeclaringType and ReflectedType

Comment: You mean the type on which the property is declared, from the type of the property?  `public class Derp{ public string Herp{get;set;}}` from `typeof(string)` you want to get `typeof(Derp)`?

Comment: Now that you put it that way :) I can see that it does not really make sence to use GetType() in this way. I think I need to get to the PropertyInfo, but not sure if it is possible from the property instance itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct link from a `Type` to a class declaring a property of that type.

You'll need to use a `PropertyInfo`:

```
PropertyInfo propInfo = model.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty");

// get the property value:
object value = propInfo.GetValue(model, null);
// get the property's declaring type:
Type declaringType = propInfo.DeclaringType;
```