# Getting model type from expression

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

I'm trying to use reflection to get the model type. So far I was able to get the type of property. But when I tried to use expression to get model type, I'm getting null reference for that property.

expression is like this,

```
model => model.property
```

and in function,

```
//I'm passing model as a parameter
MemberExpression expBody = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
model.GetType().GetProperty(expBody.Member.Name.ToString()));
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
MemberExpression expBody = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    expBody.Type.GetProperty(expBody.Member.Name.ToString()));
```

I tried this, but not working.

Comment: Please read [ask]. How do you call this ("passing model" is unclear)? How is this "not working"? What have you tried? See [Get property type by MemberExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224119/get-property-type-by-memberexpression) and [.NET reflection - Get Declaring class type from instance property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017744/net-reflection-get-declaring-class-type-from-instance-property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that your `expression` is a lambda expression whose *parameter* is model, the following produces the behaviour you expect:

```
Expression<Func<Model, string>> expression = model => model.SomeStringProperty;
Type modelType = expression.Parameters[0].Type;
MemberExpression expBody = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
PropertyInfo p = modelType.GetProperty(expBody.Member.Name);

Assert.NotNull(p);
```

Note that `modelType.GetProperty(expBody.Member.Name)` is completely unnecessary. It's preferable to extract the member from the `MemberExpression` itself in order to avoid ambiguity:

```
PropertyInfo p = (PropertyInfo)expBody.Member;
```

Comment: it throws null reference exception when I try to `.Getproperty`.

Comment: I got `propertyInfo` from expression Member as you explained. It is working. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the type of the model, just do this:

```
MemberExpression expbody = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
Type modelType = expbody.Expression.Type;
```